# MSSQL - INSERT INTO VALUES only if all Values are not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

So i have this query

```
"INSERT INTO tblAssetRelations (ParentAssetID, ChildAssetID, Type)
VALUES (
    (SELECT tblAssets.AssetID FROM tblAssets WHERE tblAssets.AssetName = $field2),
    (SELECT tblAssets.AssetID FROM tblAssets WHERE tblAssets.AssetName = $field1),
    12
    );"
```

how can i cancel/abort the INSERT statement if one of the SELECT statements in VALUES returns no value(null)

ps: $field1 and $field2 are variables for a powershell script

=====================================================================

will something like this work? im not sure about the syntax.

```
declare @Variable1, @Variable2;

set @Variable1 = SELECT tblAssets.AssetID FROM tblAssets WHERE tblAssets.AssetName= $field2
set @Variable2 = SELECT tblAssets.AssetID FROM tblAssets WHERE tblAssets.AssetName= $field1
 
 if @Variable1 IS NOT Null AND @Variable2 IS NOT Null 
    INSERT INTO tblAssetRelations (ParentAssetID, ChildAssetID, Type)
    VALUES (@Variable1, @Variable2, 12);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO tblAssetRelations (ParentAssetID, ChildAssetID, Type)
SELECT a, b, c FROM (
  SELECT
    (SELECT tblAssets.AssetID FROM tblAssets WHERE tblAssets.AssetName = $field2) AS a,
    (SELECT tblAssets.AssetID FROM tblAssets WHERE tblAssets.AssetName = $field1) AS b,
    12 AS c
  ) WHERE a IS NOT NULL AND b IS NOT NULL
```

Then you would abort the `INSERT` with `WHERE a IS NOT NULL AND b IS NOT NULL`

Comment: unfortunately this is not working because the WHERE clause only works on column attributes and is queried before the SELECT statement (after FROM table), in SSMS a, b, and c is underlined(red) and says "invalid column name" and when i start the query the error "incorrect syntax near the keyword WHERE" appears

Comment: what about using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` ?